# Multiplication returning inf in Python

Tags: python, pytorch, inf

My below function call is returning tensor of infs.

```
def regression(my_x, my_m, my_b):
    return my_m*my_x + my_b
```

`my_x` is a Pytorch tensor.
I think it is returning `inf` as it is crossing limit of float .
how can I instruct multiplication operator to use bigger data type like `float128` or `Decimal`?

Comment: You probably have to cast your floats to `Decimal`. So you'd need a special function that does this to all the floats in your tensors. And pray that nothing breaks.

Comment: Hopefully `my_x` does not contain `inf` values, which suggests that `my_m` and `my_b` are the culprits. Further assuming that the slope and intercept are fit during a learning process, it implies that an earlier optimization problem is not well-defined. Can you post more of your code or the data that led you to this problem?